# Determining whether triangles are facing each other

Tags: c#, geometry

I'm attempting to find whether two triangles are facing each other or not. I have the points forming the triangle and the order they're in (so I can use the cross product and the left hand thumb rule to gauge direction).

I should clarify what I mean by facing. The triangles do not need to be directly looking at each other, just facing in the sense that the planes each of them shares are parallel and the direction of the normal of each triangle is toward the other plane.

It gets a little tricky as I'm allowing a leeway of a few degrees for each triangle, so the planes may not necessarily be parallel.

My question is, how do I check whether the triangles are looking towards one another? (even just checking whether the normal is within 90 degrees of either side of the plan of the other triangle, the problem I have is that angle calculations just give the inner angle on these calculations).

I'm not sure how well I've described the problem. If there's any other information I can provide or something I can clarify, please ask.

Thanks.

Comment: could you provide a pic which has example 2 triangles facing each other?

Comment: "the direction of the normal of each triangle is toward the other plane" Do you mean the direction of the normal of each triangle is *normal* to the plane of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your triangles are A : A1A2A3 and B : B1B2B3

1) Compute N1, the normalized cross product of A1A2 and A1A3.
2) Test that B is 'looked' by A, that is N1 • A1B1 > 0.
3) Compute N2, the normalized cross product of B1B2 and B1B3.

If you want to test 'strict facing', then test for N1•N2 == -1  (where • is the dot product).

For less strict facing you might test for N1•N2 - (-1) < some small value.

As @BenAaronson pointed out, you might want to test if rects are in the same plane by testing (A1A2,A1A3) vs (B1B2,B1B3) to be coplanar.
 If O is the origin, test for N1•OA1 =  -  N2•OB1
( rq that here  N2 = - N1 so yo can test for  N1•OA1 = N1•OB1 ).

Comment: Presmuably you also need to check they're not in the same plane?

Comment: Hmm, that seems to work if they're both facing the same direction (so on is facing towards the other, but the other is facing away). But what about the case where they're both facing away (so if you were to take the normals of them facing each other and reverse them) it seems like it returns the same result.

Comment: Ah, thanks for updating. I actually ended up using a different method (just casting a ray from the centre of the triangle and seeing if it hits the other plane) but your method seems great, so I'll mark it as correct for anyone in the future. Thanks for taking the time to answer and update though, it's much appreciated!

Comment: Casting a ray from the center of one triangle requires to compute the cross product, so i guess your solution is very similar. Rq that you might post it also, and even accept it, no issue. Cheers !

Comment: Will do! I'll leave you with the correct answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up going with this solution, casting a ray from one triangle and checking if it collides with the plane of the other. Works well!

```
private static bool RayIntersectsPlane(Vector normal, Vector rayVector, Point planePoint, Point rayOrigin)
{
    double denom = normal.Dot(rayVector);

    if (denom < 1E-6))
    {
        Vector rayPlaneVector = planePoint - rayOrigin;
        double intersectionCheck = rayPlaneVector.Dot(normal) / denom;
        return intersectionCheck >= 0;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Method was adapted from [here!](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-7-intersecting-simple-shapes/ray-plane-and-ray-disk-intersection/)